# Calculate the flux integral by direct calculation.

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

[image]

I'm stuck on part ($a$) of this question. First I let $G(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - a^2 = 0$. Also I found the unit normal to be $n = gradG/|gradG|$. Thus using the dot product to evaluate $F\cdot n = z^2/a$. Now how do I find $dS$ and what am I integrating over?

Answer (score 1):

$dS$ is the surface area element.  The best way to compute this would be to use spherical coordinates.  Since this is the sphere of radius $a$, the surface area element is $dS = a^2 \sin{\theta} d\theta d\phi$.  Then you are integrating from $0$ to $2 \pi$ and from $0$ to $\pi$.

Comment: Thank you, but do you mind showing me what you substituted for x, y, and z?

Comment: The typical spherical coordinates are $x = a \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi), y = a \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi), z = r\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Ok, so then I get the integral a^3[0,2Pi][0,Pi]cos^2(θ)sin(θ)d(θ)d(ϕ). Correct?